# How do I install HTTP Live Streaming Tools on 10.7 Lion?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, http-live-streaming

Lion has been out for a couple of months, but the HTTP Live Streaming Tools installer reports that "This package can only be installed on Mac OSX Version 10.6.X."

Is there a way to install the tools on 10.7 Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a Bugreport with Apple about this issue.
If you have a developer account I'd advise you to do the same at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: UPDATE: Apple just released a new version and I just successfully installed on Lion!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this workaround](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16004230#16004230) to extract the package files manually.

Comment: I get this error when using mediastreamvalidator after installing using that method:

Comment: mediastreamvalidator: ERROR: Failed to impot msvlib or one of its dependencies.
Please check that msvlib is reachable from your PYTHONPATH.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mediastreamvalidator", line 23, in <module>
    import msvlib

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue.

1. Use UnPKG to unpack the `Streaming Tools Beta.pkg` file. See: http://www.timdoug.com/unpkg/
2. Go to "Streaming Tools Beta" on your desktop. `cd ~/Desktop/Streaming\ Tools\ Beta`
3. Copy all files in /. `sudo cp -r * /`
4. Edit "/usr/bin/mediastreamvalidator" and change the first line to point to python v2.6: "#!/usr/bin/python2.6"

Known issues:

- mediafilesegmenter fails with "Symbol not found: _kFigFormatDescriptionExtension_SampleDescriptionExtensionAtoms"